# Decomposition of Step-up swaps

Tags: interest-rates, derivatives, swaps, interest

is there a general procedure to decompose a fixed-floating interest rate swap, where the fixed rate changes period-to-period, into a basket of co-initial swaps, each with a different fixed rate?

For example, suppose there is a 2 year swap in which the fixed rate is 4% in year 1 and 5% in year 2. Can this be decomposed this into a long position in a 2 year swap with fixed rate 5% and a short position in a 1 year 1% annuity? If so, how could this be generalised?